# Nothing happens when click on upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I want to upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10. The software Updater shows that 14.04 is available.

[image]

But when I click on the "Upgrade" button, nothing happens. The software updater exits on clicking Upgrade.

Comment: Let me check @Wilf.

Comment: @Wilf followed http://askubuntu.com/a/311010/312849 . But, I got errors                                                                                                                         Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
    . .. . .
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not FounD

Comment: Odd... even though 13.10 is well past EOL, it appears that is still http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/ not http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/ (so you will likely have to switch back from `old-releases` to `archive`, sry). It could be another issue, probably due to the src list or cache being corrupted. It may be simpler to download a new iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, put it on a disk and to a freh reinstall - note you should backup before any update/reinstall method.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... You can try this from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo do apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An ubuntu install disk will do the trick. See the link below. It should work. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation